# type cast function arguments

Tags: c, function, casting, void-pointers

I've been playing around with type casting in C. In particular, I've been (following K&R) trying to implement a program that will take "general" types of input (specifically, K&R implements a qsort that sorts an array of pointers to generic data). In doing so, I've encountered the following issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int comp(int *a, int *b); //*a == *b

main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int *pa = &a;
    int *pb = &b;

    int (*pfunc)(void *, void *) = (int (*)(void *, void *)) comp;
    int fin = (*pfunc)((void *)pa, (void *)pb);

    printf("%d \n", fin);
}
```

This complies just fine, and does what you might expect it to do. The problem is that this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int *pa = &a;
    int *pb = &b;

    void *pVoid_a = (void *) pa;
    void *pVoid_b = (void *) pb;

    int fin_Void = (*pVoid_a == *pVoid_b);
}
```

doesn't work.

Why this is a problem: As I understand it, in the type cast

```
int (*pfunc)(void *, void *) = (int (*)(void *, void *)) comp;
```

a copy of the pointer "comp" is made, with the exception that the function this copy points to takes arguments "void *" rather than "int *", and is assigned to the variable "pfunc". Otherwise, pfunc and comp behave in the same way. (I think I must be wrong here, but I am unsure why)

When, in the first program, (void *)pa and (void *)pb are passed to pfunc, I would expect two copies of pa and pb to be made, with the exception that these are now of type (void *) and assigned to different names. These copies are sent through pcomp, the value returned is printed, etc.

I've attempted to recreate this process in the second program, except it DOESN'T work! For some reason, in the first program after pVoid_a and pVoid_b are passed to pfunc, they end up behaving like "int *"'s, in the body of the function, even though it doesn't seem like there's any reason for them to. Why do pVoid_a and pVoid_b recover their "int" behavior in the first program, but not in the second?

Comment: "A copy of the pointer `comp` is made" does not mean "a copy of the function it points to is made". It still calls the original function, which still treats its arguments as `int*`.

Comment: Although it's not the cause of your problem, and although it appears to work, it's undefined behavior to cast a function that takes int* arguments to one that takes void* arguments.

Comment: Generally, the accepted style for comparator functions to be used with `qsort()` etc is that the function does the pointer conversion, not the caller.  That is, you'd write: `int comp(const void *p1, const void *p2) { int i1 = *(int *)p1; int i2 = *(int *)p2; if (i1 < i2) return -1; else if (i1 > i2) return +1; else return 0; }` and pass this accurately typed function to `qsort()` without any cast being necessary. The standard C library `qsort()` and `bsearch()` functions take a comparator that takes `const void *` arguments. Adjust constness to your requirements. (This is different from K&R.)

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you observe in the first program occurs because any variable of type `void*` is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. In the second program, you need to explicitly state which pointer type you want to convert `pVoid_a` and `pVoid_b` to, otherwise you are dereferencing a `void*` which makes no sense. A fix:

```
int fin_Void = (*(int*)pVoid_a == *(int*)pVoid_b);
```